# Как собрать библиотеку Webpack-ом чтобы все её неиспользуемые функции и классы были отсечены при продакшен-сборке потребляющего проекта?

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, webpack

### Описание структуры библиотеки

Библиотека состоит из большого количества функций и классов, написанных на TypeScript, при этом как правило каждая функция или каждый класс находятся в отдельном файле. В этом отношении она похожа на lodash ([ссылка на репозиторий lodash](https://github.com/lodash/lodash)), однако в отличие от последнего все функции тщательно организованы по папкам. Это удобно для разработчиков, но неудобно для пользователей: ведь чтобы импортировать нужную функцию себе в проект, нужно знать, в какой папке она находится:

```
import { function1 } from "library-name/directory1/directory2/directory3";
```

Чтобы решить эту проблему, всё функции импортированы в `index.ts` и реэкспортированы из её. Теперь, пользователь может любую функцию получить как:

```
import { function1 } from "library-name";
```

### Сборка библиотеки Webpack-ом в прошлом

Библиотека компилировалась в `index.js` (правда, было два дистрибутивных файла - один для браузерного JavaScript, другой - для NodeJS; в настройках Webpack-а специально для этого есть опция `node: boolean | object`); прилагался файл `index.d.ts`.
Когда я импортировал библиотеку в потребляющий проект и тоже собрал его Webpack-ом в режиме `production`, то обнаружил, что неиспользованные функции не были отсечены Webpack-ом из выходного файла. Могу предположить, что Webpack собрал все исходные файлы в одну монолитную структуру, которую он сам же не может декомпозировать с целью отбросить неиспользуемое.

Честно говоря, я уже не вспомню, какие настройки были у Webpack-а в то время, но определённо была настройка `output: { libraryTarget: "umd" }`.

В тот момент я поступил просто: стал поставлять библиотеку в некомпилированном виде, то есть в виде набора TypeScript-файлов. Вышеописанную проблему это решило: при продакшен-сборке потребляющего проекта всё, что не использовалось, отсекалось Webpack-ом. Кроме того, больше не нужно было собирать отдельные файлы для бразузерного JavaScript и NodeJS. Но возникли другие проблемы.

### Проблемы при поставке библиотеки в виде набора TypeScript-файлов

Теперь компиляция библиотеки из TypeScript в JavaScript ложится на потребляющий проект. Я стал подозревать, что это значительно увеличивает время Webpack-компиляции по сравнению с тем случаем, когда идёт откомпилированный JavaScript файл в комплекте с `.d.ts`-файлом. Если это так, то одной этой причины достаточно для того, чтобы рассмотреть вопрос о возвращении в библиотеку компиляции в JavaScript.

Другая проблема: при сборке точки входа для NodeJS с использованием плагина `WebpackNodeExternals` нужно указывать, что вышеописанную библиотеку нужно добавлять к точке входа. Небольшое неудобство, но в идеале чтобы добавление библиотеки не влекло за собой изменение конфигурации Webpack.

### Итоговый вопрос

Итак, если уж и возвращать компиляцию библиотеки в JavaScript, то Webpack необходимо настроить таким образом, чтобы в процессе продакшен-сборки потребляющего проекта (также собираемым Webpack-ом) неиспользуемые функции и классы библиотеки были отсечены. Некоторые функции библиотеки используют другие; отсечены должны быть те, которые не используются ни напрямую в потребляющем проекте, ни косвенно через другие функции. Какими настройками Webpack этого добиться?

Кстати говоря, если посмотреть некоторые библиотеки, например серию `@aws`, то там вообще идёт аж несколько вариантов дистрибутивов в одном пакете: обычный JavaScript-файл, вариант `esm.js`, где-то`.mjs` есть... Надеюсь, нет необходимости подготавливать всё это.

### Почему нельзя просто обойтись компилятором TypeScript-а без Webpack?

Чаще всего это можно, но если мы пишем UI-кит для какого-нибудь фреймворка типа Vue, то там в исходниках могут быть не только TypeScript-файлы, но также и Vue-компонеты `.vue`, а те в свою очередь используют препроцессоры типа Pug и Sass. Тут уже однозначно Webpack. Как правило, подобные библиотеки включают в себя десятки компонентов, но реально использоваться будут лишь несколько, соответственно всё, что не используется в потребляющем проекте, необходим отсечь в процессе продакшен-сборки Webpack-ом.

Comment: почему именно webpack? смотрели в сторону gulp и подобных?

Comment: @Ghost, потому что Gulp не предназначен для сборки JavaScript-а. Вообще-то я использую Gulp уже больше 5 лет, причём настраиваю его так, чтобы всё, что связано с JavaScript/TypeScript, он делегировал Webpack-y. Но такая структура системы сборки предназначена для создания веб-сайтов и веб-приложений, а в данном вопросе речь идёт о разработке библиотек.

Answer (score 1):

советую посмотреть на такую вещь как [three shaking](https://webpack.js.org/guides/tree-shaking/), скорее всего, это то что вы ищите. выпилит из финального бандла неиспользованный код.

tree shaking работает только с **ES-модулями** и когда в package.json библиотеки указано "sideEffects": "false".

Comment: В текущем виде ваш ответ непонятен. Пожалуйста, нажмите [edit] под сообщением, чтобы добавить больше подробностей, которые помогут другим понять, как он отвечает на заданный вопрос. Вы можете найти больше информации о том, как писать хорошие ответы в [Справке](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Melnik Благодарю Вас за ответ! Пожалуйста, добавьте в Ваш ответ для его полноты, что tree shaking работает только с ES-модулями и когда в package.json библиотеки указано "sideEffects": "false". (Я попросил это сделать Вас чтобы Ваш ответ больше плюсовали и Вы быстрее набрали очки репутации).